# Why pandas automatically joins all the tables in my csv to two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, dataset

I have a data from excel, when i try to save it as csv and open it in pandas with pd.read_csv('filenames'), pandas automatically joins my csv into 2 columns and separate it with ';' symbol. Fyi, i got around 50 columns in my dataset.

Here are the image of my excel sheet and pandas dataframe.

[(excel dataframe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RZps.png)
[dataset when i import with pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWZd.png)

Comment: `read_csv` has a `sep` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the sep parameter :

```
pd.read_csv('filenames', sep=';')
```

The default separator is ','. If you look at your data you'll probably find one between 'Fund' and 'University'. Pandas think you have only two separate column and split labels like so.

The second column have NaN value because values do not contain ',' . So all values goes into the first column and no data left in the second